# How to use JSONP and how to make REST Web service that support JSONP output?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, service, jsonp

I have a project to make mobile web application using Jquery Mobile. I want that my app will consume data from cross domain REST web service. Many people said using JSONP. but i'm still confuse how to use it and how to build REST web service wich support JSONP output. Anyone can help me to tell or ilustrate the JSONP work? Or anyone have sample code for this case? Thanks before.

Comment: by which framework/technology you want to build REST service ??

Answer (score 2):

JSONP is a client side request where as REST service will be a server side request (Only if you try for cross domain api service). Both are different in terms of process.

JSONP:

You can implement JSONP using javascript or using jquery ajax method. Impleting with jquery is the easiest way. JSONP is a type that includes javascript script dynamically in your html document. So you can call js function dynamically.

There are lot of resource available for the JSONP implement. i refer the below one,

[Check this for JSONP Implementation](http://www.rajamm.info/2011/09/01/cross-domain-communications-with-jsonp-using-javascript-and-jquery/)

Below one is a simple jquery ajax function which triggers jsonp request to logitude and latitude.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: 'http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=b518527dd751af36c974e0adcdc4cb329917df46c006a72bf92858dd7c059488&ip=<?=$client_ip?>&format=json',
        success: function(data) {           
            alert(data.latitude+":"+data.longitude)                             
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Could not able to find location!');
        }
    });
```

Check [this article for REST Implemenation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Note: the error function handler is NOT called for cross-domain requests or cross-domain jsonp calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is not across the board agreement on what constitutes a RESTful web service. Definitions may include an assortment of the following:
-API url paths that are reflective of object models e.g. `user/43/comment/?datetime=01022013`
-HTTP verbs that reflect the nature of the change, e.g. `GET` shouldn't write data, etc.
-HTTP response codes map to response status, e.g. return `200 OK` only if there is not an error.

JSONP is a means by which make a request cross-domain without running into CORS security problems on the browser. While JS frameworks might abstract the reality away from you, behind the scenes JSONP is inserting a `<script>` tag into the page's DOM. JSONP url standardly includes a query paramater of `callback=<<nameForCallback>>`. Response is in javascript and is of the form:`nameForCallback({ error: false, myData: "banana"});`

JSONP always uses `GET` as its HTTP verb. API should probably always return `2XX` status code, even in the event of an error, because browsers will ignore response payload otherwise (they will not be accesible by your javascript code).

These facts rule out many of the API design aspects that would be considered part of a RESTful service. If you absolutely must use JSONP (solving the CORS problem is not possible) you can still incorporate some beneficial (to readabiltiy/maintainability) RESTful qualities into the API design, such as path routes that reflect your data models etc.

Comment: Nice explanation, but it doesn't answer the original question - which is asking how to code it.

Comment: Agreed, I'm trying to point out that JSONP and RESTful are not entirely compatable approaches. I was troubleshooting an attempt to return RESTful status codes on a JSONP endpoint this week and it took me a day to realize that it just doesn't work because of the nature of JSONP, so my answer is partly in hopes of saving some other poor sould the same struggle. :)

Comment: I see where you're going.